# Target formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running VBA to fill in all cells using last row last col. But my VBA fills in from B3 and until last row, and then adds a line below the last row and fills in to last col.

The code looks like this:

```
Sub RUNFILL()
With Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3")
    Set Target = .Range(.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Target.FormulaLocal = "=INDEKS(Sheet1!$N:$N;MATCH(Sheet3!$A:$A&Sheet3!B$1;Sheet1!$R:$R;0))"
End With
End Sub
```

I'm not sure why it fills in that way, so I'm hoping that someone can see the problem and help me correct it.

[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: shouldn't INDEKS be INDEX?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Your reference to B3 is probably making it a relative reference hence the extra row.

Comment: Delete the 0 in A1180 and your code should be fine, ofcourse along with @Sorceri 's suggestion.

Comment: Also agree with @danieltakeshi

Comment: @Sorceri INDEKS is INDEX on his excel language version, and the result #I/T is #N/A. Now i am wondering if `MATCH` is right. VBA's language is english, however, the Excel formula language is according to the language purchased. My excel is in portuguese, so i have to translate to english every time i want to make a SO question

Comment: I can't see how you don't get an error on the `.Cells(1, Columns.Count)`.  That is pointing to the cell on row 3 which is one column beyond the rightmost column of the active sheet.  Are you sure that isn't just `Cells(1, Columns.Count)` (i.e. without the leading `.`) in your code?

Comment: And isn't your code generating the formula to **two** rows below the last row, and one column beyond the last column??  (The offset by `B3` should be two rows one column more than the same range from `A1`.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider that

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3").Range("A1")
```

is equivalent to

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3")
```

and that

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3").Range("C5:D10")
```

is equivalent to

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D7:E12")
```

---

Your

```
With Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3")
    Set Target = .Range(...)
End With
```

is equivalent to

```
Set Target = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3").Range(...)
```

which is why you are not setting it to the area you think you should be.

---

But I have no idea why `Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B3").Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count)` (the expanded equivalent of `.Cells(1, Columns.Count)` in your code) is not crashing out, as that is (assuming Sheet3 is active) equivalent to `Cells(2 + 1, 1 + Columns.Count)` which will give a 1004 error due to referencing a column beyond the right-hand limit.  (And does give that error when I try to run your code.)

And I also have no idea why your code is filling in column B to the last row (but no other columns after B) and is then inserting one extra line (not two) below that which does extend beyond column B.